# In general, when are the normal, uniform and zero initializers used?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, weights-initialization

I came across a Conv2D layer in a fully convolutional network, which used a `kernel_initializer='zero'` for regression. Why is a `kernel_initializer` of `'zero'` used here?

In general, when are `'normal'`, `'uniform'` and `'zero'` initializers used?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange. Given that answer to your second question may also contain the answer to the first one, I put that more general question in the title. I would recommend that you provide the **link** to the TF implementation that uses the zero initializers for the kernel in the case of regression.

Comment: Hello, @nbro . I can't provide the link to the implementation, but the network I was looking at was a region proposal network. One of the outputs was classification (background vs non-background) and the other was regression (bounding box coordinates). The regression part of it had the zero kernel initialization.